# Django, update my jinja variable in template

Tags: jquery, django, jinja2

i have a problem, i trying to change my jinja variable when i call method post:

**Template**

```
<button id="button1">test</button>

<div class="myclass">
    {{ hosts.0.name }} <--- NEED TO CHANGE THIS VARIABLE
</div

<script>
$('button1).click(function () {
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "myurl/",
        data: {
               gfilter: "yes",
               csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
              },
        success: function(){
                 console.log("success");
                           } 
        });
        return false; 
   }); 
</script>
```

**View**

```
def templates(request):
    data = {}
    data['hosts'] = zapi.host_get() #get my initial dates
    try:
        if request.POST['gfilter'] == "yes": #<-- get dates after push button
            data['hosts'] = [{'name': 'test','host':'abc'}]
    except:
        print("except")
    print(data['hosts'])
    return render(request, 'zabbix/Templates.html', data)
```

in view i want to recive my new data when i push the button,
in view i see the data corectly but value of variable {{ hosts.0.name }} is not changed in template, Who know how resolve that case make me clear how,

thank you anticipated

Comment: What value do you have in your rendered template?

Comment: the value in template is same [ initial data ] but in view it changes